# Kotlin FXML file controller

Tags: java, javafx, kotlin, tornadofx

I am trying to make basic desktop app using Kotlin and JavaFX(TornadoFX), but I am stuck on setting up controller for FXML file.
I am following guide from edvin on git [LINK to git](https://edvin.gitbooks.io/tornadofx-guide/content/part1/10.%20FXML.html).

The program should increment number in label whenewer is the button clicked.

The problem is.. 
When I try to use FXML file shown below, I can't use `onAction="#increment"` to "connect" that file with a controller.
This will compile, but there is no way to call increment function from controller.kt file. Also there is error saying "No controller specified for top level element" ..

Whenever I try to specify the controller by using `fx:controller=view.Controller` the code will not even compile, showing error:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: Controller value already specified.
```

Could someone please help me out?

**Here is FXML file**:

```
?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/null" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <padding>
        <Insets top="20" right="20" bottom="20" left="20"/>
    </padding>

    <center>
        <VBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="10">
            <Label text="0">
                <font>
                    <Font size="20"/>
                </font>
            </Label>
            <Button text="Click to increment" onAction="#increment"/>
        </VBox>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

**Here is MyApp.kt** (main file):

```
package app

import javafx.stage.Stage
import tornadofx.*
import view.MainView

class MyApp: App(MainView::class){
    override val primaryView = MainView::class

    override fun start(stage: Stage) {
        stage.minHeight = 400.0
        stage.minWidth = 600.0
        super.start(stage)
    }

}
```

**Here is MainView.kt** (view):

```
package view

import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane
import tornadofx.*

class MainView : View() {

    override val root: BorderPane by fxml("/views/MainViewFXML.fxml" )
}
```

**Here is Controller.kt** (this should be used to control FXML file actions):

```
package view

class Controller {

    fun increment(){
        //code
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In TornadoFX, the View *IS* the controller. Think of View subclasses as the View Controller. React to UI events in the View, and pass business logic off to a ViewModel or a Controller subclass.

Place your `increment` function in `MainView` and it will be called :) Remove the `fx:controller=view.Controller` attribute.

Comment: Thank you that worked out well. But could I have one more question please ? When I have my MainView.kt same as is yours in the guide, it won't compile, the error is probably somewhere in "init{ counterLabel.bind(counter )}" ... it tells me "Unresolved reference", Error:(14, 22) but I do not have idea how to fix that.

Comment: Please raise an issue on the guide project and I'll have a look at it ASAP :)

Comment: So I have fixed my issue, it was caused by importing "java.awt.Label" instead of "javafx.scene.control.Label". So thank you for your time, you helped me a lot.

Comment: Great! Thanks for reporting back :)